# Using some information word for word from one answer to another?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've recently seen two questions, **in which are not duplicates**, but have some similarities. I have answered one of the questions already, but the answer that I wrote contains a paragraph or two that I believe will be useful to this second question.

I wanted to know if copy and pasting paragraph(s) of text from one answer written by me, to another answer that I will write (both answers will have other information, therefore they will not be identical) is against the terms of service or is "wrong" to do.

- Should I reword my paragraph, and then include it in the second question?
- Is doing the above against the Terms of Service or unmoral?
- Should I write a comment to the OP of the second question like the example below?

> I have an answer that contains some information that might be helpful
>   to you here: `link-to-my-previous-answer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only using a short paragraph or two from a longer answer of yours to another question, then I would see no issue with re-using them in a new answer to another question, with the link you suggest being optional.

However, at the same time, if you are using this content to answer two questions that are really duplicates, then instead you should vote/flag for them to be closed as such.